# Sign patterns: Cardinality of $\text{sign} (V)$ for a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Define the $\text{sign}(.)$ function as $\text{sign}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \{-1,0,1\}^n$ which gives you the sign of each coordinate of a given vector.

It is clear that $\text{sign}$ is surjective. Now if we want to restrict this function to a given subspace $V$ of  $\mathbb{R}^n,$ things get a bit more complicated.

My question is: **What is the cardinality of $\text{sign}(V)$ in such a case?**

---

At first, I thought I would be able to make use of the structure of $\mathbb{F}^n_3$ but that did not work, $\text{sign}(V)$ need not be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{F}_3^n$ in general.

For a hyper-plane, all we need is to count how many times we can have at least one negative sign and at least one positive sign, plus the obvious $(0,\cdots, 0)$.

Now I know that every subspace is an intersection of hyperplanes, but I have no idea if this would even be useful.

---

Comment: Side note: Another interesting (imo) direction where this could be taken is to ask for bounds on $\dim \text{span}_{\mathbb{F}_3^n} (\text{sign}(V))$ in terms of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of $sign(V)$ is at least $3^{\dim V}$, and this lower bound can be achieved (say, if $V$ is generated by vectors of the form $(0,\ldots, 0,1,0,\ldots,0)$).

To see this, simply choose a basis of $V$, and write its vectors as rows of a matrix.  Applying row reduction to this matrix (and reordering its columns if necessary), we get a $(\dim V \times n)$-matrix of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} I & | & *\end{pmatrix} $$
where I is the identity $(\dim V\times \dim V)$-matrix, and $*$ can be any $(\dim V\times (n-\dim V))$-matrix.

The rows of this matrix form a basis of $V$, up to the same reordering of the columns as above.  From there, it is easy to see that vectors in $V$ can have any combination of signs for their $\dim V$ first entries.  Thus there are at least $3^{\dim V}$ elements in $sign(V)$.

The exact number of elements in $sign(V)$ will depend on the matrix $*$; describing all possibilities seems a more difficult problem.